# Ember: loading Template not working when promise returned from Application Route

Tags: ember.js, routes, loading

I don't understand why the loading template is not loaded in the following scenario

```
App = Ember.Application.create()

App.Router.map ->
  this.resource 'dashboard', {path: "/"}

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  beforeModel: ->
    new Ember.RSVP.Promise (resolve) ->
      Ember.run.later ->
        resolve()
      , 3000

App.DashboardRoute = Ember.Route.extend      
  model: ->
    ['red', 'yellow', 'blue']
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jageg/2/edit?html,js,output

From the [documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/) I understood that if a route with the path `dashboard` returns a promise that doesn't immediately resolve, Ember will try to find a loading route in the hierarchy that it can transition into.

Thanks.

Comment: I wanted this as well, but seems to be [disabled by design](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/90397ef15453da1cba1f6bda374e075f054bfdf4/packages/ember/tests/routing/substates_test.js#L195).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the loading route of the parent resource will be placed into the parent resource's `{{outlet}}`.  Unfortunately for you, you're blocking the top most resource, so Ember can't render the application template and it's loading route because of that.

If you block one level lower, it will hit the loading route of the application resource, which is just `loading`.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/babuzi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. In my real life example though, I am loading the current user in the application route and if the server is down for some reasons, I won't be able to display neither a `loading` template first nor an `error` template later. So what's the best approach for loading the current user data. I need the current user because then I'll perform authorization policies based on the user's status.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same problem. Did you find a nice way to solve this issue? The only solution I can think of is put the whole app in a nested route ("example.com/app"), this way you could move the `application` model to `app`.. Doesn't feel like the right solution though..

Comment: In the latest versions of Ember a loading route exists above the application template.